# Ubuntu 18.04 how Gedit does Auto Indent / Auto Format my HTML document?

Tags: gedit, plugins

I have been looking for how to auto indent / auto format my HTML document using Gedit.
I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and Gedit with a BLACK color scheme. Love Ubuntu! Love black color scheme.

My friend using Windows and a Microsoft development showed to me a method to auto format a HTML document. The program just organized whole HTML document as a "Tree" of HTML and Tags.

I have been trying to do this using Gedit but no success. I have tried to install MANY (more than 15 plugins), but usually they don't do what I want.

[image]

I could see this recurse on Atom and Geany editor, but I want this on Gedit.

I have a HTML document very Mess.

And I want Gedit re-organize whole document and create a "tree" of tags.

Comment: I'm not confident gedit is sophisticated enough for what you really want. Is there any particular reason you don't just use Atom or Geany (if they already do what you want)

Comment: Sublime also has this feature. I don't think GEdit has it though.